# Issues Upgrading httpd from 2.4.37 to 2.4.46

Tags: yum, httpd, centos8

I removed httpd 2.4.37 and tried to install 2.4.46 from raven-extras repo but the package is not showing it just says the following

```
All matches were filtered out by modular filtering for argument: httpd
Error: Unable to find a match: httpd
```

However, If I try to install httpd from raven-extras repo on a fresh machine, the package shows and installs. So its only not showing if I remove the old package and try to install the updated package from raven-extras repo. If yum install httpd with AppStream repo enabled, httpd 2.4.37 shows.  I need to upgrade 2.4.37 to 2.4.46 that is why im doing this.

Any help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact the repo maintainer. They should have provided their build of httpd as a module, but apparently did not. It will not be installable until they do so.

Comment: Thank Michael, I will do that